# Usar Translate en Angular2 dentro del fichero .ts

Tags: angular

Siempre he hecho el translate en el html, pero ahora tengo que hacerlo en el `.ts` y me devuelve un [object object] en el html y no sé que hago mal.

```
headerName: translate.get("Name");
```

También he probado con :

```
translate.get("Name" : string | Aray<string>);
```

Para que supuestamente me devuelva el campo y no un Object Object pero dice que esperaba 1-2argumentos y encontró 14.

```
translate.getTranslation('Name') : Observable <any> ....
```

Pero tampoco me funciona, ya no sé que probar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que estás usando [ngx-tranlate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core):

Entonces sabrás ya que las traducciones se guardan en un objeto que se crea desde un JSON, algo como:

```
{
 "name": "nombre",
 "pantallaLogin": {
   "user: "Usuario",
   "password": "Contraseña"
 },
 ...
}
```

Entonces, ¿cómo funciona el API?

El método `translateService.get('<clave>')` devuelve un `Observable<string | Object>`:

Con el ejemplo puesto, `translateService.get('pantallaLogin.user')` devolvería un observable que al resolverse te daría el valor `"Usuario"`, pero con `translateService.get('pantallaLogin')` el Observable se resolvería con todo el objeto:  `{ "user: "Usuario", "password": "Contraseña" }` (En ambos casos estoy asumiendo que el idioma actual es el español, claro).

También acepta un array de Strings, en cuyo caso te devolverá un objeto cuyas entradas serán todas las claves que has pedido:

`translateService.get(['pantallaLogin.user','pantallaLogin.password'])` devolverá un Observable que se dará un objeto así:

```
{ 'pantallaLogin.user':'Usuario','pantallaLogin.password':'Contraseña'}
```

Por encima tienes el método `translateService.getTranslation('<lang>');`
Si le pasas como parámetro `'es'`, te devolverá un Observable, que se resuelve con todo el fichero `es.json`, es decir, todas las entradas del idioma español.